# Apple certificates CER file to CSR

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I am a little lost in apple certificates and what I need. I created development certificate, some profiles and so (for my use). Now I am adding some features to existing app which creates someone else but it's my job now and for next I was asked for giving UDID and creating CSR file. UDID is clear but how can I create CSR file? I should give it and then I get provisioning profile from other person. I hope it's clear. So how can I get CSR for my development profile?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you already have provisioning profile. Provisioning profile is something that connects certificate (developer) with UDID's (allowed devices) and bundle identifier (app identifier).

If you have valid provisioning profile (contains your device, correct app identifier etc.) you only need to set it to be used in xcode under build configuration.

If you really need CSR (certificate signing request), something that is used to generate new certificate - you use keychain for that (Keychain access -> Certificate assistant ...). You can find detailed information on CSR generation in memeber center of iOS developer program (Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Certificates -> + ). From some time handling of provisioning profiles is almost automatically handled by Xcode when you try to build app for your device.